# Initializing a CCSprite with a png

Tags: png, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

I'm starting to use Cocos2dx and I'm having an issue creating a CCSprite from a .png I have. It's like it couldn't found the image from the resources or it is not compatible, because if I choose another one, it works. I also tried with a jpg and it didn't work, so apparently, it just works with some kind of images.

How can I make an image compatible for the CCSprite?

Thanks

Comment: you are jumping to conclusions, post the actual results (ie error/warn message) from your initial attempts. More likely the file couldn't be found.

Comment: There is no error. I just send a path to the constructor of the CCSprite and it can't found the resource. I don't know if I have to add it from Eclipse to the project or what.

Comment: It must have a error log or something check your console. I think cocos2d-x support all kinds of png.

Comment: Which IDE you used to code cocos2d-x? Cause I use X-code and each time I add new source files I have to quit and re-open Z-code, so that X-code can update new files. If I don't re-open, X-code will return can not open source  files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add it the project as build-native.sh (or.bat) does that.

The image should be in the folder called 'resources' (which will be in the same folder as 'Classes' and 'Proj.Android'.

When you build you app it will be copied in proj.android/assets so check that it gets put in there after you build.